# Windows mobile device with credit card swipe and printer?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, printing, credit-card

We're looking to produce a custopm application for a client written in .Net.

The application will have a basic inventory and the user will sell an item, swipe the customer's credit card and take the payment.

Is there a device that runs Windows Mobile and has a Credit Card swipe facility and a Printer in one?

If not any recommendations for a PDA/Printer/Swiper combo? Or a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Socket SOMO650 with the Socket Mag Stripe Reader Card 4E expansion card?

The only disadvantage with using a Socket is that you'll need to use their SDK 'SocketScan' that, if I recall correctly, is close to a thousand pounds.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for an all-in-one, but something like this should work.